# which QR code SDK is the best for integrating in an iphone app

Tags: iphone, sdk, qr-code

I am beginner in iphone programming I have to do a project for my course and I have 1 month left.
what I have to do is that application scan qr code and load information like media and text from mysql database relevant to that object.
can you please guide me which SDK is more easy to learn for me as a beginner and also convenient for this project?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used ZBar SDK In my app..it is pretty easy to use and is also customizable.

http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/index.html

Comment: Thanks, could you please tell me, is this possible to load information like media and text on the screen after qr code detected, which loaded from mysql database relevant to that qr code in application or not and how difficult is implementing such an app?